# Pages are not accessible, menu links are not displaying properly

Tags: routes, users

I'm trying to resurrect a Drupal 4 site which stopped working at some unknown point, possibly months ago. I can login as admin and reach the front page. Every link after that returns 'you are not authorized to access this page'. The primary_links and secondary_links menus are not being retrieved properly. I have tried switching themes and clearing the cache table. I have also set up a local version for debugging but there are no PHP errors being thrown.

I'm running php 5.2.13, mysql 5.1.44.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have noted in the comments of the first answer, the issue was due to a change in versions of PHP. The bug was previously reported [here](http://drupal.org/node/92802).

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebuild the node permissions?  I think the direct link to that in D5 is /admin/content/node-settings/rebuild if it isn't in a menu.

Comment: No, I can't get to any of the admin pages. I always get   'you are not authorized to access the page'. I'm not clear whether it's a permissions error, or if I'm just getting 403s. The 'custom error' module was enabled and was throwing a predefined error message which was linked to a 403 result. I disabled it in the db and the error I get now is the access error described above.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all non-core modules via the database?

Comment: No, but I did try to remove all the non-core module folders. (They were actually inside the root modules folder instead of sites/all/modules). I then put back the 'front' module as I was getting WSOD, and the front page came back, but with the same issues as before.

Comment: Does your users table have an entry for uid==0?

Comment: Are you getting an Apache 403 page or a Drupal 403?

Comment: Yes, there is a uid 0. I will take a look at the 403 when I'm back in the office but I think it's probably Drupal.

Comment: Some further clues. The 403 is a Drupal error, thrown when case = MENU_ACCESS_DENIED in index.php
I have restored the db using an older backup and the primary and secondary links now show. Many of those links are driven by the taxonomy_menu module. If I go into that module and disable the $may_cache clause in the menu hook, the links work OK and show the page.
However, I still get the page access error if I try to go into any of the admin pages.

Comment: This was due to the bug reported here, where the session failed in php 5.2: [link](http://drupal.org/node/92802). I should apologetically point out that the site in question is running Drupal 4, not Drupal 5.

Answer (score 0):

Both PHP and MySQL was on version 4 around this time, I would suggest you start by trying to go back to PHP/MySQL 4, either, or both. If possible ofcourse, the versions the site was built upon. I can see in one of the comments that this conclusion may already have been drawn. I mainly came here to answer the question because [community](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) bumped it as an unanswered question.

Accept my answer or the first one, but please accept one. :)